# AC in Countable Union of Countable Sets

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice

If I understand correctly, AC is not needed in the case of a finite union of countable sets because the choice function can be built with recursion, using the case of 2 sets (which is straight-forward).
However, why is AC needed in the case of $\omega$ countable sets (or $\alpha$  infinite (well-ordered) sets, for $\omega\leq\alpha\in\text{Ord}$)?

If we take the choice function $G$ to be $\bigcup_{n<\omega}G_n$, where $G_n$ is the choice function for the case of $n$-sets union, such that $\forall m<n \;\; G_m\subseteq G_n$, then $G$ will also be a function and a choice function.

Where's my mistake/where do I implicitly use AC?

Thanks

Comment: You are *choosing* each $G_n$ among many possible choice functions, which is infinitely many choices

Comment: $G_n$ is the choice function for a union of $n$ countable sets, and it can be chosen (with recursion) like in the case of a union of 2 countable sets, no? Given $G_{n-1}$, $G_n$ will be $G_{n-1}$ union a bijective function $A_n\to\mathbb N$ (where $A_n$ is the n'th set), which can be chosen by definition

Comment: Also, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/717961/countable-axiom-of-choice-why-you-cant-prove-it-from-just-zf https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2816939/when-induction-proofs-need-a-choice-function https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/307277/why-isnt-this-a-valid-argument-to-the-proof-of-the-axiom-of-countable-choice and many many others dealing with these sort of arguments.

Comment: @idan What you can do with arbitrarily large finite sets isn't necessarily possible with infinite ones.

Comment: Also to clarify on your second comment, you're saying *"$G_n$ the choice function ..."*, but there is no *the* choice function. There are *many* choice functions.

Comment: My mistake. However I read the other links and what I understood is: if it's finite it's possible, if not you need the AC "just because" (but there's got to be a more logical reason). If it's needed because arbitrary choice is not trivial, then why do finite union (and binary union) of countable sets doesn't need AC? And if the latter is true, then what fails when taking the union of $G_n$? They are functions (monotonic by $\subseteq$) that I constructed using recursion on ordinals, so the union should also be a function

Comment: Because you can make finitely many choices. In addition to all the links so far, see also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1839913/axiom-of-choice-where-does-my-argument-for-proving-the-axiom-of-choice-fail-he and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/365269/intuition-behind-the-axiom-of-choice